# streaming live video from android to wowza

Tags: android, streaming, live, wowza

I'm  trying to make an android app that sends live video from the  phone camera to wowza media server using eclipse and android sdk.I tried to use the spydroid ip camera on code.google (this is the link https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)    but i could'nt know exactly what to change in this app to make it stream to my localhost wowza server.The tutorial that comes with spydroid is not clear(this is the link to the tutorial:https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/issues/detail?id=2) .Can you help me please ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 4):

For all of you who still looking for answer - try looking at [fyhertz lib](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/wiki/Using-libstreaming-with-Wowza-Media-Server). I think it's easy to apply and stable enough